# error cannot read property count of undeifned

Tags: javascript

i have an oData controller sending me count of total entities which i am trying to read in javascript i.e. an angular app. The odata.count property is visible with a proper value but i keep on getting error. please refer to the attached image.

[image: snapshot of an error]

when i try to read

```
countResponse.odata.count
```

i get this error that cannot read property count of undefined.

please guide

Comment: The screenshot is helpful, but please also post the code itself.

Comment: Does it work when you try: `countResponse["odata.count"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you have a property name with a dot. Your code is trying to access an object on `countResponse` called `odata` and then `odata`'s `count`.

Either change whatever code sets up this property to not use periods or change the syntax to be `countResponse["odata.count"]`.

Comment: thankyou. it worked. ill accept is as an answer in 8 minutes.